Split a PIL image into multiple regions with a patch included in one of the split region
I need to write a python code that accepts a PIL image and split the image into M rows and N columns, such that one of the split region completely contains a patch of height H and width W starting at point (p,q).
I am mostly able to write the code and my attempt is shown below, but not able to generalise for any M and N. For example it sometimes breaks down for M=3, N=1.
Can someone help me out on this by either suggesting what change to make in the below code or any other way using PIL or Numpy.
--- EDIT (Adding more details on the limitations of the below piece of code)
The main issue with the below code is that the splitting is agnostic to point (p,q) and patch dimensions H,W i.e. split regions are only decided based on M,N and height and width of the original image. To be more precise if in the below code the patch is NOT completely included inside one of the split region then the split regions should re-adjust to make sure the patch is completely contained withing a split region. Its dine if split regions are non-uniform dimensions. Infact its better of the split region containing the full patch is of smallest size.
from PIL import Image

def split_image_with_path(image, M, N, H, W, p, q):
  """
  Splits a PIL image into M rows and N columns, ensuring one split region contains a path of height H and width W starting at point (p,q).

  Args:
    image: A PIL Image object.
    M: Number of rows to split the image into.
    N: Number of columns to split the image into.
    H: Height of the patch.
    W: Width of the patch.
    p: Starting x-coordinate of the path.
    q: Starting y-coordinate of the path.

  Returns:
    A list of PIL Image objects, representing the split image regions such that one of the split region contains the specified patch
  """

  width, height = image.size

  # Calculate the size of each split region.
  split_width = width // N
  split_height = height // M

  # Ensure the path is completely contained within one split region.
  if not (p < split_width * N and q < split_height * M and p + W <= split_width * N and q + H <= split_height * M):
    raise ValueError("Path is not completely contained within one split region.")

  # Split the image into M rows and N columns.
  split_images = []
  for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
      left = j * split_width
      right = (j + 1) * split_width
      top = i * split_height
      bottom = (i + 1) * split_height
      split_images.append(image.crop((left, top, right, bottom)))

  return split_images

dummy_image = Image.open("/path/to/image.jpg")
display(dummy_image)

splits = split_image_with_path(dummy_image, M=3, N=1, H=100, W=100, p=10, q=10)

for split in splits:
  display(split)


I don't understand problem. Code seems OK and it should work with any values. If it doesn't work then you have to better describe it in question (not in comments). Don't expect that we will run it to see problem. Besides it may work correctly on our computers. We can use different images with different sizes and all may works correctly.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

if path has to be completely contained within one split region then you should check it inside for-loops and use left, top, right, bottom

you should assume (at start) that complete_contained = False, and inside loops check left <= .. < right top <= ... < bottom (without not) and set complete_contained = True, and after loop you can check if not complete_contained to raise error.

Based on @furas comment i have added more detail to the question.

It seems it need something different. Ir regions have to be the same size but you can change N,M then you have to start with N=1 (it should always completely contain), next check for N=2, next N=3, etc. if for some N it doesn't fit then you should keep N-1. Later repeat it for M. And it doesn't need to use loop to check all regions but it needs modulo segment_width - if p modulo split_width is equal p+W modulo split_width then both elements are in the same region.

problem can be when you can't change N,M but regions can have different sizes. It is simple to find region for path because it is p, p+W, q, q+H but problem is to split rest of image into N-1,M-1 regions.

Its the second case. M,N cannot change but regions can have different sizes.

I don't know - for N=1 it makes no problem to get all region, for N=2 you may use p or p+W to split into 2 regions and both p andp+W will be in the same region. For N=3 you can use both p and p+W and you get 3 regions. But for N>4 it starts make problem. You can still use p and p+W to create 3 regions but you have somehow split other regions (which don't have path) into more regions - to get N regions.

I'm not sure what is problem but I see one mistake.
OR maybe I don't understand what you try do do
If path has to be completely contained within one split region
then you should check it inside for-loops and use left, top, right, bottom for this.
You should also assume at start complete_contained = False
and inside for-loops check left <= .. < right and  top <= ... < bottom (without not) and set complete_contained = True when it is completely inside this region. But not set False if it not completely inside this region.
And after loops you can check if not complete_contained to raise error.
Something like this:
# Ensure the path is completely contained within one split region.

complete_contained = False
  
split_images = []

for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):

        left = j * split_width
        right = (j + 1) * split_width
        top = i * split_height
        bottom = (i + 1) * split_height

        split_images.append(image.crop((left, top, right, bottom)))

        if (left <= p < right) and (top <= q < bottom) and (left <= p + W < right) and (top <= q + H <bottom):
            complete_contained = True
      
if not complete_contained:
    raise ValueError("Path is not completely contained within one split region.")


I would write loops little different - maybe more readable.
And I would use names x,y instead of i,j because they seem more readable
for y in range(0, height, split_height):
    for x in range(0, width, split_width):

        left = x
        right = left + split_width
        top = y
        bottom = top + split_height

        split_images.append(image.crop((left, top, right, bottom)))
        
        if (left <= p < right) and (top <= q < bottom) and (left <= p + W < right) and (top <= q + H <bottom):
            complete_contained = True


I'm wondering about other think: when you divide it then it may create smaller regions on right and bottom sides - and it seems you skip them.
For example M=6, width=100 gives (100//6)*6 = 96 so it skips 4 pixels.

My issue is that the splitting is agnostic to point (p,q) i.e. split regions are only decided based on M,N. To be more precise if complete_contained is False the split regions should re-adjust to make sure the patch is completely contained withing a split region.
